# nginx serve subdirectory path as argument

Tags: nginx

I'd like to serve the subdirectory path as an argument. For example:

http://www.example.com/whatever

Actually goes to:

http://www.example.com/?arg=whatever

But is still shown as the original request URL.

A path to a file should do the same:

http://www.example.com/whatever/image.png

Actually goes to:

http://www.example.com/?arg=whatever/image.png

I'm not that experienced with nginx, and I haven't found or been able to create what I would like. So far the furthest I have come was with the following:

```
location ~ /(?<anydirectsubdirectory>[^/]+) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?project=$anydirectsubdirectory;
}
```

But this only gives me the first directory, and I have no idea or could find anything that explains what any of that does, so if you have a link to an explanation of whatever that is that would help me a little further.

Answer (score 1):

Uh, I may have totally overlooked the easiest solution ever:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?project=$request_uri;
}
```

If this is not the *proper* way, feel free to still answer! I like things clean.

Comment: This is the preferred way of implementing front-controller pattern in nginx.